# Automatically generate serial version UID in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I frequently use the Eclipse quick fix to generate a serial version UID for serializable classes.

Is there any way to do this by default?

It's one extra click, but with Eclipse selecting quick fixes is generally slowish, and I always generate serial version UID:s when I implement serializable.

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is perhaps not the answer you're looking for. Presumably, you use Eclipse to generate the same special value that Java would automatically calculate for your class if you didn't explicitly specify it, something like:

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4125965356358329466L;
```

But there's no good reason to rely on this same algorithm for newly authored classes. What matters is you specify a value, any value. So why not simply do the following?

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

You could then put this code in Eclipse's new class template.

Comment: This certainly makes sense, and accurately tells me what I can and can't do with eclipse.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if you have got answer to this. But Eclipse does allow to create `serialVersionUID` in one go for all classes implementing `Serializable`. Although, it is not exactly same what you want. However, it will serve the purpose with fewer clicks.

Right-click ***Project -> Source -> Clean Up...***

- Select *Use custom profile*. then click *Configure*

[image: clean-up-screen-1]

- Click *Missing Code* tab. Under *Potential programming problems* select *Add serial cersion ID*. Click *OK*

[image: clean-up-screen-2]

- Now you will see one step being added as highlighted

[image: clean-up-screen-3]

After clicking *Finish*, Eclipse will generate `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: This step by step worked perfectly for me. tks

Answer (score 3):

In Ecplise

remove the line from your class

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789L;
```

put your mouse over the method's name (ex : XxxMethod) that implements Serializable

click on "add generated serial version ID"

Comment: You're describing the quick fix. The OP specifically said he wants an automated alternative.